# Putting a warning flag on a particular version

Tags: version-control, cvs

I have 4 versions of a file 1.21, 1.22, 1.23 and 1.24. After a month of time I came to know that the version 1.22 and 1.23 have some errors in them. Now I don't want anyone to use those versions. One way to solve it is to delete those versions, but I don't want to delete them. I just want to know a way so that if anyone checkout those obsolete versions they should get a warning or custom message that "don't use this version, this version has some problems".

Is there any way to do this? Let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CVS has no such function.

If you don't want to change the file itself, you have to modify whatever points to those revisions (tags, documentation etc.).

Answer (score 0):

As @CL says, there is no function to do this.

What I would encourage, and I have seen this in many places, is to add not only a comment in a revision notice text file, but also a file titled "faulty_deprecated-do_not_use.txt" or similar as part of the distribution/package to help make it as obvious as possible.